# OpenGL c++ - unwanted black triangle appears

Tags: c++, opengl

I started working on a simple GUI application using OpenGL. Drawing a simple background quad makes a lot of difficulties and I just can't spot what I am doing wrong or what's 'broken'. Here is the part of the code which is responsible for drawing my background 'quad':

```
static void Draw(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(-1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex2f(1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex2f(-1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("Pro Sound");
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyPressed);
    glutKeyboardUpFunc(keyUp);

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

The output looks like a gray quad, but on top of it (right side) there is a black triangle with vertices on the centre, top right corner and bottom right corner. So my background looks like bitten by a triangle-teeth pixel monster. The thing is, it recently worked properly, I even could add some textures, position it well etc.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are drawing the quad vertices in the wrong order. Vertices should be ordered, by default, in a counter-clockwise fashion along the perimeter of the polygon.

So what you have is:

```
(-1.0f, -1.0f)  Bottom-Left
( 1.0f, -1.0f)  Bottom-Right
(-1.0f,  1.0f)  Top-Left
( 1.0f,  1.0f)  Top-Right
```

which is creating:

[image]

When you want:

```
(-1.0f, -1.0f)  Bottom-Left
( 1.0f, -1.0f)  Bottom-Right
( 1.0f,  1.0f)  Top-Right
(-1.0f,  1.0f)  Top-Left
```

which creates:

[image]

See also [Face Culling](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Face_Culling) and [Primitive - Quads](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Primitive#Quads)

Comment: So simple, yet enlightening. Thanks a lot my savior. Salute!

Comment: He's using `GL_QUADS` so it would draw a quad, not two triangles.

Comment: All modern GPUs consume only triangles, so it is being triangulated by the driver into two triangles. If the GPU worked on quads then he would not of seen the artifact he saw.

Comment: Precisely.  Most of the stuff you see with OpenGL is now transformed into triangles and shadered- because it's the fast path.  So much so, that even with the transforms, it's faster.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `GL_QUADS` and changing your coordinates, keep your coordinates and use `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`.

I'm fairly certain `GL_QUADS` is deprecated, and it seems to be good practice to use `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` or `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` whether you are drawing quads or not.

The only time you should use `GL_QUADS` is when you are in immediate mode and sketching up a small program in which performance does not matter. (This may be one of those times; but for reinforcement and good measure, I always use `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` or `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`.)

Comment: Yes, Quads were deprecated in 3.0 and removed entirely in 3.1. This is a good point to make.

Comment: Will get into it right away. Thanks for your time, appreciate it, sir.